# Meteor display html formatted text in template

Tags: mongodb, meteor, bootstrap-wysiwyg

I'm using meteor 0.9.1.1.

I've just gotten mcrider:bootstrap-wysiwyg working for the body of a note or article.  It saves to the mongo collection field just fine, but when I try to display it in a template, the html is display rather than applied.  In other words  something that should look like this:

- lets keep this content
- in a list
- with lines
- etc

instead shows all the raw html tags need to record the formatting along with the core text.

I hope there is a simple function I can pass it through to get the desired results.

Any ideas?

Thanks, Alex

Comment: Can you give some code to show what you're doing? Are you trying to inject html into a template?

Comment: Turns out I just needed triple handlebars around my variable.

Answer (score 19):

Use `{{{field}}}` instead of `{{field}}` in your HTML template if you want the HTML code in `field` to be interpreted as HTML code (and not escaped).

Comment: If you do this, and any user is able to submit an article, make sure you whitelist the HTML input on the server to protect against XSS.